# Mouse buttons up events ignored in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, mouseevent

The following piece of code should report mouse clicks events but no Bx-Up events are ever reported... Is that a bug or did I miss something ?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# coding: UTF-8

# Testing mouse events in tkinter

import tkinter as tk

class MyMouse:

    def __init__(self):

        def init_vars():

            self.padx, self.pady = 40, 40
            self.xsize, self.ysize = 800, 600

        def create_window():

            def create_canvas(wdth, hght):
                canvas = tk.Canvas(mywin, width=wdth, height=hght, bg='white')
                canvas.bind(sequence='<1>', func=self.b1)
                canvas.bind(sequence='<B1-Motion>', func=self.b1_motion)
                canvas.bind(sequence='<B1-Up>', func=self.b1_up)
                canvas.bind(sequence='<2>', func=self.b2)
                canvas.bind(sequence='<B2-Motion>', func=self.b2_motion)
                canvas.bind(sequence='<B2-Up>', func=self.b2_up)
                canvas.bind(sequence='<3>', func=self.b3)
                canvas.bind(sequence='<B3-Motion>', func=self.b3_motion)
                canvas.bind(sequence='<B3-Up>', func=self.b3_up)
                return canvas

            mywin = tk.Tk()
            mywin.title("Testing mouse events in tkinter")
            mywin.canvas = create_canvas(self.xsize, self.ysize)
            mywin.canvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, padx=self.padx, pady=self.pady,
                                expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
            return mywin

        init_vars()
        self.mywin = create_window()
        self.mywin.mainloop()


    def b1(self, event):
        print('b1 called', (event.x, event.y), flush=True)

    def b1_motion(self, event):
        print('b1_motion called', (event.x, event.y), flush=True)

    def b1_up(self, event):
        print('b1_up called', (event.x, event.y), flush=True)

    def b2(self, event):
        print('b2 called', (event.x, event.y), flush=True)

    def b2_motion(self, event):
        print('b2_motion called', (event.x, event.y), flush=True)

    def b2_up(self, event):
        print('b2_up called', (event.x, event.y), flush=True)

    def b3(self, event):
        print('b3 called', (event.x, event.y), flush=True)

    def b3_motion(self, event):
        print('b3_motion called', (event.x, event.y), flush=True)

    def b3_up(self, event):
        print('b3_up called', (event.x, event.y), flush=True)

MyMouse()
```

reports:

```
b1 called (452, 238)
b1 called (452, 238)
b1 called (452, 238)
b1 called (452, 238)
b2 called (452, 238)
b2 called (452, 238)
b3 called (452, 238)
b3 called (452, 238)
b3 called (452, 238)
b1 called (381, 242)
b1_motion called (381, 243)
b1_motion called (399, 255)
b1_motion called (410, 262)
b1_motion called (413, 263)
b2 called (415, 264)
```

Comments : I Believe the preceding question is largely self-sufficient but the program won't allow me to add some more comments. So please ask questions so that I can add more comments as needed. This post is about events managers which are never called...

Comment: You might want to consider cutting this down to a [mcve]. Do you really need all of the mouse bindings to illustrate this, or would be the bindings only on one be sufficient?

Comment: changing the button makes clearer that there was no up before the button change

Comment: Perhaps, but that means you only need to include two buttons rather than three.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see `B1-Up` on the documentation:
http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm

I do see, however, `ButtonRelease-1`. That is the correct event to bind to.

Comment: I found the generic construction of an event name in some X-window documentation and this construction doesn't cause any error (writing `Bx-UP` or `Bx-up` causes an error). But you're right, this solves the problem. thank-you.
Now, there still might be a bug in the fact that `Bx-Up` should either cause an error, or be processed.

Comment: @Camion: `<B1-Up>` isn't an error. It means "Press of mouse button 1 followed immediately by  press of the Up button".

Comment: I might have made mistake but based my code on this information (https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/bind.htm) or a similar one. the point is that it didn't cause any error (writing Bx-UP or Bx-up causes an error). But you're right, this solves the problem. thank-you. Now, there still might be a bug in the fact that Bx-Up should either cause an error, or be processed.

Comment: Sorry, @Bryan Oakley, I wanted to redo my comment. But Ok, thank you. I just tested it and it does that. That's quite tricky X-D

Comment: @Camion: like I said, it's not an error. "Up" refers to the up-arrow key rather than the state of the button.